# Open MS Access Form at Specific Record - Adding Extra Table to Form Record Source Stops Correct Behaviour

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I've got a form that I use to enter new orders. I want to open the form at a specific record (Order), so I set up a button on another form with the following VBA attached:

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()
   DoCmd.OpenForm "frmOrderEntry", , , "[OrderID] = 1"
End Sub
```

This works correctly, but only when **frmOrderEntry** is already open in Design Mode. When the form isn't open already, then it opens on a new order. Configurations for **frmOrderEntry** are as follows:

Default View: **Single Form**
Recordset Type: **Dynaset**
Pop Up: **Yes**
Modal: **Yes**
Cycle: **All Records**

Can anyone help me?

Cheers,

**EDIT:**

After a bit of digging around, it seems that it was an issue with my Query. I had added a new table (ShippingDetails) to frmOrderEntry's Record Source, but put the wrong join type in (INNER JOIN, instead of LEFT JOIN):

```
SELECT tblOrder.*, tblOrderStatus.*, tblCustomer.EmailAddress,
tblShippingDetail.*
FROM (tblOrderStatus INNER JOIN (tblCustomer INNER JOIN tblOrder ON
tblCustomer.CustomerID = tblOrder.CustomerID_FK) ON
tblOrderStatus.OrderStatusID = tblOrder.OrderStatusID_FK) **LEFT JOIN**
tblShippingDetail ON tblOrder.OrderID = tblShippingDetail.OrderIDShip_CK;
```

Still not sure why it let me open the form at a specific record when it was already open in Design Mode.

Cheers,

Aiden

Comment: The ID that you pass in the filter is a Long, Integer or Text ?

Comment: The datatype of [OrderID] in the Order table is Long Integer. The statement above is what's passed into the filter I assume("[OrderID] = 1"). Would that be a string? Or would it be interpreted as Integer?

Comment: I don't think the parameter is the problem. Popup and/or Modal forms behave differently when opened from Design view vs. from being closed. So it hat to do something with these properties.

Comment: I've tried messing with the frmOrderEntry configurations. But I still can't get it to work. I had this behaviour working on a backed-up version of the DB, with all the same configurations. I can't understand it. I'm not sure now whether I should have used a different tool to develop this DB (my first). Access seems really fragile / unpredictable.